# why the python modules installed in my kali linux machine do not run in the repository

Tags: python, linux

I installed 007spam-BOT in my kali-linux machine and when i ran it, it says that no modules found named lib.utils  and is not running. here are some screenshots for your reference:

Files:

[image: file system]

Error:

[image: error]

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: with normal pip command which is used in normal python programming

Comment: What version of python are you using? According to the issues - https://github.com/mrwn007/007spam-BOT/issues/5 - running `python3 bot.py` can help

Answer (score 0):

From the error that you are showing, I believe that you have not installed the `lib` module.
You can install it through pip using: `pip install libs`